# Are any of these SDKs known to violate the Google Play policy?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I have developed and published several apps on the Play Store. Because of an old ads sdk (which had a security issue), I had to update all my apps with the new compliant ads sdk.

The problem is that once I update my apps, the update got rejected with this message :

> This is a notification that your application, ***, for package
>   ID ***, has been removed from Google Play.
>
> Please address the issue described below and submit a compliant
>   update. Once approved, your application will again be available with
>   all installs, ratings and reviews intact.
>
> REASON FOR REMOVAL:Violation of section 4.3 of the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement.Please refer to the policy help article for
>   more information.
>
> We classify user information including but not limited to, email
>   address, phone number, name, social media account information, and
>   contacts as private and confidential information.
>
> An app downloaded from Google Play (or its components or derivative
>   elements) which transmits this information off of the device without
>   making this clear to the user and obtaining the user’s explicit
>   consent are regarded as being in violation of section 4.3 of the DDA.
>
> All removals are tracked. Repeated removals will result in app
>   suspension, at which point this app will count as a strike against the
>   good standing of your developer account and no longer be available on
>   Google Play.
>
> This notification also serves as notice for other apps in your
>   catalog. You can avoid future removals and/or app suspensions by
>   immediately ensuring that no other apps in your catalog are in
>   violation of (but not limited to) the above policy. Before publishing
>   applications, please ensure your apps’ compliance with the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit
>   this Google Play Help Center article.
>
> The Google Play Team

I am using several ads SDKs :

```
AdMob (Play services 7.5), AppBrain (10.51), Vungle(3.3.1), InMobi(4.5.5) and StartApp(3.1.1)
```

I also use analytics :

```
Google Analytics (Play services 7.5), Crashlytics (Fabric.io, 2.3)
```

Here are all the permissions I ask for :

```
CAMERA, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
INTERNET, VIBRATE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, BILLING and CHECK_LICENSE
```

and the features :

```
android.hardware.camera, android.hardware.camera.autofocus, 
android.hardware.camera.front, android.hardware.wifi-required=false
and android.hardware.touchscreen-required=false
```

And now, my app has been suspended.
I have absolutely no idea of what could be the cause -> is this a specific SDK issue ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an app distribution channel, not programming. Non-programming questions about app stores are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare It may be a programming question as a ads SDK might be the reason. I have no other place to post this, I just beg for an answer. I bought you ebook, I thought you were on the developers side -disappointed.

Comment: "I have no other place to post this" -- there are [many Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com). Your question may be on topic for some of the others.

Comment: @CommonsWare These are no big enough communities such as StackOverflow to be able to answer my question. I am simply asking a question where I can get answers. What about the fact it could be programming related ?

Comment: @MathieudeBrito Actually, it is not. You are asking something about Google Play's policy. That's not something related to programming, sorry.

Comment: Better questions would be: 'How do I list permissions added by third party libraries?' and 'Are any of these SDKs known to violate the Google Play policy?' (list each SDK and version number)

Comment: @blackcj, this is a useful answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by one of two issues. Either you're using an SDK that is not compliant with the Google Play policy or your SDKs are adding permissions that you're not accounting for in your privacy policy.

This thread may be helpful:
http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/3584-google-play-developer-term-violation-4.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer @blackcj I already read this article. I have no trace of what they talk about in my SDK, even after decompiling it. As you said, I think one of the SDK I have is not compliant with Google, so I will try removing most of the ads SDK I have, and keep only Google, I hope this will to the trick. I keep the subject on for some time, trying to get more responses and if not, your answer will be marked as the one.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest SDKs. It's possible that previous versions are no longer compliant. There was another article that referenced StartApp as causing this issue as well.

Comment: I actually have the latests sdk. Do you have any link about this StartApp issue please ? this might be very useful !

Comment: A number of people your situation have had success reaching out to the Google Play Team for more details (but that could take a week or more for response). At least then you'd know for sure which SDK is the culprit.  http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/3406-suspended-app-because-startapp-post-call-manager.html

Comment: Very interesting, thank you so much dude, You gave me hope !

Comment: Thank you @blackcj, I have the final answer : the new version of Crashlytics from Fabric.io was the issue. It appears that it sends some personnal information that I was not aware of. So I removed it and the update worked.